# CarrierWave resize_and_pad method always uses white

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, carrierwave

I've scratched my head over this for quite a while. I have a screenshot uploader class which uploads to AWS. The issue lies with `resize_and_pad` as the image is correctly resized and padded however regardless of what Hexcode I enter the background is always padded with white.

How can I get the padding to be black instead of white?

```
class ScreenshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  require 'carrierwave/processing/rmagick'
    include CarrierWave::RMagick
    process resize_and_pad: [200, 100, "#000000"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to switch to the **Mini_Magick** library instead of Rmagick and everything worked as expected.

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mini_magick'
class ScreenshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   process resize_and_pad: [200, 100, "#000", "Center"]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

resize_and_pad takes in 4 parameters, you're missing one parameter: gravity.

> process resize_and_pad : [200,100,"#000000",Magick::CenterGravity]

should do it.

Here's the official doc: [link](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/MiniMagick.html#M000057)

Comment: Hi rb, I have tried adding this in previously but it still comes out as white.

Comment: it worked for me.  i would check if image-magick really pads the image.  it won't pad it with the given color if the image is small and requires no padding.  try uploading an image with a larger aspect ration than 200x100.